# Getting all values in one column as a json when input(s) is value from another column

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with  a column id and customers in postgresql database.Id and customers have one-to-many relationship.I would like to input id(s) as json and get corresponding customers as json using python.How could it do it?Any advice please?

Answer (score 1):

Let the database do that for you:

```
SELECT id,jsonb_agg(customers) 
FROM your_table  
GROUP BY id
```

Demo:

```
WITH t (id, customers) AS (
  VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,42) )
SELECT id,jsonb_agg(customers) FROM t  
GROUP BY id;

 id | jsonb_agg 
----+-----------
  1 | [1, 2, 3]
  2 | [42]
(2 rows)
```